# How to display service configuration ?

Tags: symfony, configuration, twig

Is there built-in functionality in Symfony2 which display the configuration of all services (or selected one)? For example I would like to know if Twig has autoescape turned on.

Answer (score 0):

Imho You can only use the

```
php app/console container:debug
```

Next you need to check constructors and yaml files.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if such command exists by default, but you can always have a look at the compiled XML file that is generated. It may be located in something like `app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.xml`.

If you want to make it handy you can write a command that will dump it for you. You can access to the parameters using [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container::getParameterBag()](http://api.symfony.com/2.1/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.html).

e.g.

```
$parameters = $this->getContainer()->getParameterBag()->all();
```

Don't forget to make it extends `ContainerAwareCommand` :

```
class MyCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
```

Beware that the parameter you are looking for may not be present in the output, as it can use an **implicit** default value.

Finally you can also use `config:dump-reference` in order to get the default configuration of a service that exposes a [semantic configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html).

e.g.

```
php app/console config:dump-reference twig
```